# @RefreshScope alternative for entire application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

While working with spring cloud config I have come across @RefreshScope.

As I understood @RefreshScope must be used with any beans who needs to get the dynamic update of the used properties.

Is there a global alternative available which can be used across the application instead of just a bean?